# Django Queryset + looking for all objects that have ALL values in an array in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I am hard coding it here, but in reality this array can have between 1 and 99 values

```
looking_for = ['blue', 'red', 'green']

objects = MyObj.objects.filter(colors__name__in=looking_for)
```

will give me all the objects that have ONE of the colors in `['blue', 'red', 'green'`]

But I want the objects that have ALL the colors objects with the names mentioned in the array. I want `AND` not `OR`. Could not find how to do that. any ideas?

** UPDATE **

I was able to find a solution.

```
objects = MyObj.objects.all()
for l in looking_for:
   objects = objects.filter(colors__name__in=l)
```

the resulting `objects` will only have those who have all 3 color objects as specified by the array.

Comment: Please share the relevant model(s).

Comment: This is a generic question, the model has nothing to do with it. I specified the `colors` is a many-to-many field to a color object that has the field `name`. In any case. I found the answer -- will post it in the body of the question. Thank you.